# Removing Everything to the Right of a REGEX Expression

Tags: r, regex, string, data-manipulation

I have the following data that looks like this:

```
my_data = c("red A1B 5L2  101", "blue A1C 5L8  10872", "Green A1D 5L5  100003" )
```

**Starting from the right hand side of each string, I wanted to remove the number as well as the spaces before the number.**

The final result would look something like this:

```
[1] "red A1B 5L2"   "blue A1C 5L8"  "Green A1D 5L5"
```

I know that there is a regex pattern that appears in each string in the following format: `'(([A-Z] ?[0-9]){3})|.', '\\1'`

Thus, I want to identify the position where this regex pattern finishes and the position where the string finishes - then I could delete the space between these two positions and obtain the desired result.

I found this link which shows how to remove all characters in a string appearing to the left or to the right of a certain pattern (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/removing-strings-after-a-certain-character-in-a-given-text). I tried to apply the logic provided here to my example:

```
gsub("(([A-Z] ?[0-9]){3})|.', '\\1.*","",my_data)
```

But this is producing the opposite result!

```
[1] "red   101"      "blue   10872"   "Green   100003"
```

Can someone please show me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub()` here:

```r
my_data <- c("red A1B 5L2  101", "blue A1C 5L8  10872", "Green A1D 5L5  100003" )
output <- sub("\\s+\\d+$", "", my_data)
output

[1] "red A1B 5L2"   "blue A1C 5L8"  "Green A1D 5L5"
```

The regex pattern used here is `\s+\d+$` and matches one or more whitespace characters followed by one or more digits at the end of the string.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen : Thank you for your answer! I tried this on my real data and it is not always working - is there any way to use the logic I am using and adapt the code? THank you so much!

Comment: Maybe edit your question and include the edge cases.  I have given a valid answer per what you actually asked above.

Answer (score 1):

Using `trimws` in `base R`

```
trimws(my_data, whitespace = "\\s+\\S+")
[1] "red A1B 5L2"   "blue A1C 5L8"  "Green A1D 5L5"
```